# How can I use pmml model in PySpark script?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pmml

I have `xgboost` model, which was trained on pure `Python` and converted to `pmml` format. Now I need to use this model in `PySpark` script, but I out of ideas, how can I realize it. Are there methods that allow import `pmml` model in `Python` and use it for predict? Thanks for any suggestions.

BR, 
Vladimir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark does not support importing from PMML directly. While I have not encountered a pyspark PMML importer there is one for java (https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator-spark). What you can do is wrap the java (or scala) so you can access it from python (e.g. see http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/09/01/spark-calling-scala-code-from-pyspark.html).

Comment: Hi, @Assaf! Thanks for your attention. But I have one more answer, can I do this things with Spark 1.6, or it's need to apply ani adaptations?

Comment: @VladimirSazonov You would need to dig a little into pyspark as there may be small changes. The logic should be similar though

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PyPMML-Spark](https://github.com/autodeployai/pypmml-spark) to import PMML in PySpark script, for example:

```
from pypmml_spark import ScoreModel

model = ScoreModel.fromFile('the/pmml/file/path')
score_df = model.transform(df)
```

Comment: Have tried to use a PMML model in the way suggested above, but the model predictions do not match with those of original model. There is a shift of 5% to 10% in the predicted probabilities. Also for around 5% of the rows in input dataframe, the output probabilities by PMML model are NaN. Whereas for the exact same rows, the original model is predicting fine.